# Concentration inequality or a general bound on $\mathbb{E}[||\mathbb{E}[X]-X||]$

Tags: probability-theory, matrix-calculus, probability-limit-theorems, random-matrices, concentration-of-measure

Given a matrix random variable $X \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ is there a concentration or any interesting upper-bound on the following expression:

1. $ \mathbb{E}[||\mathbb{E}[X]-X||] \leq  ??$

Information I have are spectral properties of the mean $\mathbb{E}[X]$.

2. Secondly, given that we have another estimator $S_n=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ where $X_i$ (iid) like the random variable $X$ can I say something, about $ \mathbb{E}[||\mathbb{E}[S]-S||] $ where the expectation is on all $X_i$s.

The only idea I had first was to use Jensen's inequality with:
$ \leq \mathbb{E}_{X,Y}[|| X - Y||]$, which leads again nowhere.

Comment: Well, on a probability space $\| f \|_{L^1} \leq \| f \|_{L^2}$, so you can bound it by the "standard deviation" i.e. $E[|E[X]-X|^2]^{1/2}$. I'm not sure there's much better you can do in the first problem without more specific information. In the second case you need some kind of a uniform integrability or domination condition in order to get an estimate (since you have a.s. convergence by SLLN, you then need uniform integrability to get $L^1$ convergence).

Comment: By the $||.||$ I simply mean any norm on the matrix.

Comment: I know what you meant, my statement goes through regardless of what norm you have in mind.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly there is always a positive constant $a$ s.t. I can always bound the expression $\mathbb{E}[||\mathbb{E}[X]-X||] \leq a \mathbb{E}[(\mathbb{E}[X]-X)^2]^{1/2} $

Comment: That constant is just $1$. (This depends on us being on specifically a probability space rather than a general measure space or even just a general finite measure space.) But make sure you note that I took the norm of $E[X]-X$ before squaring.

Comment: Thank you very much. For the second case say that we have a bound on $a<||X||<b$, can this help us to establish some argument along the lines of law-of-large numbers in the second case?

Comment: So $|X|$ is uniformly bounded? That's enough to get convergence of $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ in $L^1$, and technically enough to make this convergence quantitative. But you will need to have some idea of how fast $S_n$ converges in probability to $E[X]$ in order to make this quantification.

Comment: Well I do not know that, and I was hoping there is some general inequality, given $(n,a,b,d)$ and some moment properties of $X$.

Comment: Have you tried understanding the rate of the convergence in probability through Chebyshev's inequality?

Comment: In fact it is simpler: since you know it is between a and b you get a variance bound for free then you can apply my first comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The most straightforward bound here is that the mean absolute deviation is bounded by the standard deviation.
2. In view of the bound given in 1, if $X_i$ are iid random variables with 2 moments and $\overline{X}_n=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n}$, then $E[|E[X]-\overline{X}_n|]$ is bounded by the standard deviation of $\overline{X}_n$, which is $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$. In the particular case where $a \leq |X| \leq b$, $\sigma \leq \frac{b-a}{2}$.